# Create Table not working

Tags: mysql

Forgive me if the question is very simplistic; I am a bit of a novice when it comes to SQL. The following CREATE TABLE syntax was generated by MySQL workbench from my model; It gives me `errno: 150`. Anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong gets a cookie (and my gratitude!).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mealPlannerApp`.`ingredients` (
`ingredientId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`stub` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
`photo` INT NULL,
`description` TEXT NULL,
`servingSizeInGrams` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`cost` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`calories` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`protein` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`carboydrates` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`fat` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`saturatedFat` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`transFat` INT UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT ,
`cholesterol` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`sodium` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`dietaryFiber` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
`sugars` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ingredientId`),
UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`ingredientId` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `stub_UNIQUE` (`stub` ASC),
INDEX `photo` (`photo` ASC),
INDEX `name` (`name` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `photoId`
FOREIGN KEY (`photo`)
REFERENCES `mealPlannerApp`.`photos` (`photoId`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Show the photos table.

Answer (score 1):

Error 150 is a FOREIGN KEY related error so I bet that you didn't create the table `mealPlannerApp`.`photos` before `mealPlannerApp`.`ingredients` (which is mandatory).

Otherwise, you have some bad practices in your query:

- PK on ingredientId and unique index id_UNIQUE are duplicates (useless and will generate extra-load)
- The ASC option in your indexes definition is understand by MySQL but not implemented (useless), maybe it's Workbench which has generated this.

Comment: The `ASC` is redundant but not useless.

Comment: @ypercube can you explain?

Comment: From MySQL documentation "An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order."

Comment: My disagreement is merely linguistic. I think redundant is more appropriate here (than useless). If I declare two indexes, one with `INDEX (a ASC)` and another with `INDEX (b DESC)`, mysql will accept both and create them as `ASC` indexes. But the definition is not entirely useless. It's still in my create scripts so the next admin/developer knows the purpose of the indexes and if we move to another dbms or in a future version of mysql that can distinguish between these 2 kinds on indexes, it can be useful.

Comment: Yes but why move from MySQL ? :) Just kiding, in my opinion MySQL would not accept the ASC, DESC keywords because some DBAs can think that create an descendant index is possible.

Comment: Thanks! You are quite right; I haven't yet created the photos table. Creating the whole schema failed for about half the tables and so I worked out some of the problems but when I try to create the tables individually they don't work. I guess that's why so many tables didn't create; problem with a table that the remainder are dependent on via foreign key leads to all the rest of them not working because the table they need doesn't exist yet. I'll see if this fixes my problem when I get home tonight  :)

Comment: Disable FKs, CREATE the tables, then Enable FKs.